# Magento: Manually Restore Truncated "core_config_data" Table

Tags: sql, database, magento

I've just installed a local copy of Magento. For some reason, importing the sample data overwrites the admin_users table and totally empties the core_config_data table. Restoring my admin user access is easy but restoring the configuration is impossible for me at the moment (yes, it's my fault. I forgot to backup my database before importing)

Say, anybody here who knows the keys to the configuration file or better if you can share a copy of the Magento configuration table?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch. This is why the test data instructions tell you to import the sample data first and then do the Magento install.

Given the quantity of data in the core_config_data table, it will be easier to reinstall Magento to recover it as its contents are created by all the install scripts in each module and the contents vary from version to version.

There is the possibility that you can create the skeleton contents for the core_config_data table from [here (magereverse.com)](http://www.magereverse.com/) by using the appropriate sections out of the structure dump.